# Invalid Table Name duirng MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem with the below SQL. It fails saying

```
MERGE INTO MFK_WORK_KEYS mfk
USING (
    select t_1.puid AS puid,
        'Cfg0AbsFamilyThread' AS domain,
        t_1.pcfg0FamilyNamespace || t_2.pfnd0ThreadId AS key_value
    from
        PCFG0ABSFAMILYTHREAD t_1 JOIN PFND0WSOTHREAD t_2
    ON t_2.puid = t_1.puid
    where t_1.puid not in
        (select puid from  union select puid from PFND_TRACELINK)
) t
ON (t.puid = mfk.puid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    mfk.domain = t.domain,
    mfk.key_value = t.key_value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
        mfk.puid, mfk.domain, mfk.key_value
    ) VALUES (t.puid, t.domain, t.key_value);
```

This is on Oracle.

I could see the tables MFK_WORK_KEYS/PCFG0ABSFAMILYTHREAD/PFND0WSOTHREAD/PFND_TRACELINK in the database. I am clue less as to why it complains about a missing table.

Reuqest in you guys to share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same in Oracle as it is in SQL Server, but on there, the table that's going to be affected is determined purely by the `INTO` clause. As such, there's no need to use table names (or aliases) on the left side of assignments for the `UPDATE` nor in the column list for the `INSERT`:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    domain = t.domain,
    key_value = t.key_value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
        puid, domain, key_value
    ) VALUES (t.puid, t.domain, t.key_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the inner SQL statements is wrong.

MERGE INTO MFK_WORK_KEYS mfk USING (select t_1.puid AS puid, 'Cfg0AbsFamilyThread' AS domain, t_1.pcfg0FamilyNamespace || t_2.pfnd0ThreadId AS key_value  from PCFG0ABSFAMILYTHREAD t_1 JOIN PFND0WSOTHREAD t_2 ON t_2.puid = t_1.puid where t_1.puid not in (  select puid from  union select puid from PFND_TRACELINK )) t ON ( t.puid = mfk.puid ) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mfk.domain = t.domain, mfk.key_value = t.key_value WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( mfk.puid, mfk.domain, mfk.key_value )  VALUES ( t.puid, t.domain, t.key_value );

Notice that : select puid from  union select puid from PFND_TRACELINK is not valid.

When I correct it to select puid from PFND_TRACELINK, and have fired the whole SQL block, the merge happened.

Comment: I conveyed the same to the concerned team and they did acknowledge this as the SQL problem.